# How to add many rows without memory leak?

Tags: python, django, memory-leaks

How can I add more than 3-4 millions entries to a database table in django?

I tried using `bulk_create`, but this is giving a memory leak: the script uses more than 500mb and takes very long to execute.

When I do it using Flask+SQLAlchemy, I use `add all` and all entries are created in 2-3 minutes.

When I do it using Symfony+Doctrine ORM, all entries are created in 3-4 minutes.

How i can do it in django?

Comment: Did you try with debugging turned off in project settings?

Comment: @LudwikTrammer I even ran the script without running the project and still the same problem.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what "running a script without running the project" even mean... In any case make sure debugging is set to False.

Comment: @LudwikTrammer it means that i run script in the console `python script.py`..

Comment: But your models are still in a project, aren't they?

Comment: Did you try altering the `batch_size` argument? By default `bulk_create()` tries to load everything in a single SQL statement.

Comment: @mhawke yes, i set `batch_size=300`.